# Web Scraping Dropdown List Using JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am creating a bot for that will generate a link to any shoe on Adidas.com, and then check the available sizes of the shoe, given the shoe's model # and a user's shoe size.

To get the available sizes of the shoe, I am using JSoup for web scraping. Adidas implements a dropdown list for users to select their desired size for any given shoe. When I inspect the dropdown, the web page has quite a few nested elements, but I determined that actual list of available sizes was this block of code below:

```
<select class="select___Kst06">
    <option value="defaultOption" disabled="" hidden=""></option>
    <option value="0">5</option>
    <option value="1">6</option>
    <option value="2">7</option>
    <option value="3">7.5</option>
    <option value="4">8</option>
    <option value="5">8.5</option>
    <option value="6">9</option>
    <option value="7">9.5</option>
    <option value="8">10</option>
    <option value="9">10.5</option>
    <option value="10">11</option>
    <option value="11">11.5</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">12.5</option>
    <option value="14">13</option>
    <option value="15">14</option>
</select>
```

Now, given this list, I want to retrieve these values and return them in my code. I have this method here to do just that:

```
public static String[] checkSizes(String addr) {
    String[] sizesAvailable = null;
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(addr).get();
        Elements sizes = document.select(".select___Kst06");
        sizesAvailable = new String[sizes.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.size(); i++) {
            sizesAvailable[i] = sizes.get(i).text();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sizesAvailable;
}
```

However, when I run the method, I get an empty array `[]` returned. I have tried a myriad of selector syntax combinations, but to no avail. Methinks it shouldn't be very hard, but I am just missing that obvious query. What am I doing wrong in this instance?

I am new to JSoup, so bear with me. And if anyone would like to inspect this for themselves, [here](https://www.adidas.com/us/af-1.4-primeknit-shoes/BY9395.html?forceSelSize=BY9395_710) is a link to the 'test' shoe, if you will. Every shoe on the site has the same template. Thank you for your help in advance.